# Dependency injection efficiency/performance SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, dependency-injection

So I've been trying some concepts for dependency injection in a SwiftUI app. I've come up with this through several examples :

```
struct WageListView: View { 
   
   @ObservedObject viewModel: WageFileLoader

   init(dependencies: HasWageFileLoader) {
      viewModel = dependencies.injectWageFileLoader()
   }

   var body: some View {
      // View stuff
   }
}

protocol HasWageFileLoader {
   func injectWageFileLoader() -> WageFileLoader
}

class Dependencies: HasWageFileLoader {
   private let wageFileLoader = WageFileLoader()

   func injectWageFileLoader() -> WageFileLoader {
      return wageFileLoader
   }
}
```

Now this works correctly for every object that depends on WageFileLoader. However I've noticed of course that every time WageFileLoader changes that the view gets reloaded / rebuilt and also calls the injectWageFileLoader method again.

Is this an ok way of doing this? I've noticed some performance issues injecting dependencies this way in stead of using initializers and injecting dependencies through the parent class / view. Am I right? Or am I imagining things? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In SwiftUI views can be re/created very often and in unexpected moment, we almost do not control this activity, so view model life-time should be very careful and under our control. So think about usage of `StateObject` if view is single logically and should has persistent view model or use external storage and inject view models from parent. That's actually depends on your app logic.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for your comment. I've read a bit about StateObject. So StateObject should be used in the view that creates the (Observable) object right? Which in my example is the WageFileLoader class. Then in the other views I should use ObservedObject or EnvironmentObject?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overthinking it, it's worth fully learning SwiftUI before trying to apply other patterns because you might end up introducing the consistency bugs typical of objects that Swift/SwiftUI eliminate via use of value types and the `View` data struct. We can pass params into Views or we can use `.environmentObject` if a child View requires the object when intermediaries do not.

Another tool SwiftUI offers is `DynamicProperty` where a struct can access the Environment in the `update` func. This func is called on these properties just before `body` and this is how the `FetchRequest` struct gets the `managedObjectContext` from the environment. It also uses an `@StateObject` as the delegate of the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

It's also worth thinking about previews. `@StateObject` are not init during previews (so they run faster). Usually we have a singleton for previewing, see the `Persistence` struct in the project template with Core Data checked.

If you are using files take a look at [`Documents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/documents) it does a lot of the work for you.

Comment: Hey malhal. Ok so I shouldn't worry too much about performance issues? I mean I know views get created crazy fast. I just wasn't used to the fact that all the instances a view holds also get created over and over. This is different in UIKit where the view(Controller) created an instance of a ViewModel and held on to that for the rest of the App's lifecycle right?